# Putting space about labels for vertices and shifting these labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

A line is drawn through a side of two triangles.  One of these lines are drawn on top of the labels B' and C' for vertices of one triangle.  I used the option `inner sep=2pt` to put some space about these nodes.  No space was allowed.

Also, for the line drawn through B' and C', I have an extra pair of arrowheads.  I know that I have this for separating the domain into two parts and using the option `latex-latex`.  How do I remove the arrowheads near B' and C'?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,clip=false,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-7,xmax=26,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-7,ymax=30,
restrict y to domain=-7:30,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[dashed,latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-6:25]{x};


\draw (axis cs:-3,-3) coordinate(A) node[above left]{$A$};
\draw (axis cs:0,10.5) coordinate(B) node[above left]{$B$};
\draw (axis cs:5,13) coordinate(C) node[above]{$C$};
\draw (axis cs:3,9) coordinate(P);

\draw (axis cs:10.5,0) coordinate(b) node[anchor=north, inner sep=2pt]{$B^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:13,5) coordinate(c) node[anchor=south west,inner sep=2pt]{$C^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:9,3) coordinate(p);

\addplot[dashed,latex-latex,samples=2,line width=0.2pt,loosely dash dot,domain=7:10.5]{2 * x - 21};
\addplot[dashed,latex-latex,samples=2,line width=0.2pt,loosely dash dot,domain=13:25]{2 * x - 21};

\addplot[dashed,latex-latex,samples=2,line width=0.2pt,loosely dash dot,domain=-7:25]{0.5 * x + 10.5};
\end{axis}

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (P);
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);

\draw[dashed] (A) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
\draw[dotted] (b) -- (p);
\tkzMarkRightAngle[densely dotted](A,p,b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `north west` and `west` anchors for B' and C', respectively, to generate some additional separation. Actually, the default `inner sep` is bigger than `2pt` in your case (it is `0.3333em` by default, according to page 229 if the 3.0 manual), so removing the `inner sep` option generates additional space.

<strike>For the arrow heads, the reason is that you have two lines specified with the same formula but different domains. Combining the domains into one plot produces one arrowhead.</strike>

For the arrow heads, you can specify that an arrow head should be on only one end of the line by writing `latex-` or `-latex`, i.e. arrow head->line or line->arrow head. It is unnecessary to specify `dashed` and `loosely dash dot` for the same plot.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,clip=false,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-7,xmax=26,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-7,ymax=30,
restrict y to domain=-7:30,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[dashed,latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-6:25]{x};


\draw (axis cs:-3,-3) coordinate(A) node[above left]{$A$};
\draw (axis cs:0,10.5) coordinate(B) node[above left]{$B$};
\draw (axis cs:5,13) coordinate(C) node[above]{$C$};
\draw (axis cs:3,9) coordinate(P);

\draw (axis cs:10.5,0) coordinate(b) node[anchor=north west]{$B^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:13,5) coordinate(c) node[anchor=west]{$C^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:9,3) coordinate(p);

\addplot[latex-,samples=2,line width=0.2pt,loosely dash dot,domain=7:10.5]{2 * x - 21};
\addplot[-latex,samples=2,line width=0.2pt,loosely dash dot,domain=13:25]{2 * x - 21};


\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,line width=0.2pt,loosely dash dot,domain=-7:25]{0.5 * x + 10.5};
\end{axis}

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (P);
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);

\draw[dashed] (A) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
\draw[dotted] (b) -- (p);
\tkzMarkRightAngle[densely dotted](A,p,b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The placement of the vertices is nice.  I do not want the line going through the triangle because the sides of the triangle would be of different patterns.  There must be a command to put an arrowhead on a ray.

Comment: @Adelyn See my edit. Hope it helps! :-)